# Is there a verb for listening stealthily?

Tags: word-request

I am wondering if there's a verb that means "listening stealthily" or "listening to someone or a group of people without having him/them know".

I am highly confident that there's a verb, but I can't seem to remember what it was.

Just so that we're in the same page, here's an example:

> John put his ears over the door to ___ at the private conversation between the king and the queen.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

The word you're looking for is probably *eavesdrop*:

> Secretly listen to a conversation.
> *‘my father eavesdropped on my phone calls’*

<sub>(source: [Lexico powered by Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/definition/eavesdrop))</sub>

@Zikato reminded me of [this scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpOF1NHowdQ) from The Fellowship of the Ring where Sam is caught eavesdropping (around 2:45) on a secret conversation between Gandalf and Frodo.

Comment: I ain't been droppin' no eaves sir, honest.

Answer (score 9):

While I think eavesdrop is probably your best choice, *spy* would also be an appropriate descriptor for the action of stealthily listening though it does include all kinds of observation, so watching (and I suppose smelling?) as well.

> Observe (someone) furtively.

(Source: [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spy) )

Answer (score 7):

You can use **to listen in**.

It can be used either without an object, or with one. In that case, you listen in **on** something.

Definition and examples from the [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/listen):

> **listen in**
>
> Listen to a private conversation, especially secretly.
>
> - *Seth listened in as his father chatted philosophy with friends*
> - *I hurried him into my room and shut the door behind us; I didn't want any eavesdroppers listening in on our conversation.*
> - *At this point, I decided to stop listening in on their private conversation.*

Answer (score 6):

This is more of a visual, (perhaps even *nasal*), term, but it doesn't rule out listening:

> **snoop**
>    intransitive verb
>
> : to look or pry especially in a sneaking or meddlesome manner
>
> *She locks up her diary to keep her brother from snooping.*
>
> -- [MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snoop)

Comment: Why do you suggest it's nasal?

Comment: @bubbleking, Well there's [*"that funny-looking kid with the big nose"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snoopy).  The *sn* sound is a well known [phonestheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonestheme#Examples) pertaining to the nose and mouth; a more detailed listing can be found in [*Phonaesthesia and the faculties of performance: 3.1 Analysis of the data*](https://www.academia.edu/234791/Phonaesthesia_and_the_faculties_of_performance).

Comment: Fascinating information!

Answer (score 5):

A word that means "listening to someone or a group of people without having him/them know" but not "listening stealthily" is *overhear*

> Hear (someone or something) without meaning to or without the knowledge of the speaker.
>   ‘I overheard two doctors discussing my case.’

(source: usage from [collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overhear) and definition from [oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overhear))

Comment: Overhearing is usually unintended, not deliberate as in the question.

Comment: well yes, but that's not what the question was asking.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that **eavesdrop** is a good word for this.

An alternative synonym is **earwig**

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/earwig) definition

> British informal
>
> Secretly listen to a conversation.
>
> *‘he looked behind him to see if anyone was earwigging’*

Answer (score 2):

In this case ‘spy’ could do as well, though that indicates more than just listening, it’s more ‘observing stealthily’

Comment: Hi Patrick, "spy" has already been suggested in [another answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/206555/30156).